# How do I override the default location for the .grails folder from the command line?

Tags: grails

In a unix environment, I want the .grails folder to go somewhere other than the default location, and I want to set this from the command line... I believe the command should be something like:

`grails -Duser.home=/x/y/z run-app`

but this doesn't seem to be working. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line switch you're looking for is:

```
-Dgrails.work.dir
```

I wrote up a [blog post](http://naleid.com/blog/2010/05/07/using-a-unique-grails-working-directory-for-each-mercurial-branch/) last month that has a script to have a unique grails working directory based on the mercurial branch that you're working in (so you can easily switch between them without getting weird compilation errors).  You might find the script useful.